Is there any way to monitor which meta questions/suggestions might be picked and made functional?
The process of tracking development of new site features is very unclear. 
Other related questions:

Who decides if a suggested feature is site-worthy?
Who implements the different suggestions that are deemed site-worthy?
How/Where are the new feature implementation being tracked if at all?
If none of the process is in-place, of what value is it to make site feature suggestions?

Assuming nothing exists, should the community not implement a vote based mechanism to have new features applied to the site?

As a moderator, I don't have any control over software changes. I can only change configuration settings like help text. I looked at several other questions labeled feature-request, and I didn't see any responses from the Stack Exchange team. If I were you, I'd post feature requests to meta.se, and use this site for discussions of how to use the software we already have.

Before implementing a feature you should:

Post it on the relevant site (here in this case), to get support.
Once you have support, you can then escalate to the Meta SE site. 

Without proper site support, it's unlikely you'll get a new feature added.
